# How to split a group even further than below? (Regex)

Tags: regex, algorithm, expression, regex-group

I am working on creating a table using an expression generate in Regx.

The expression I have so far is:

> TABLE\s+GENERATOR\s+([a-z]\w*)\s*((\s*(?:[a-z]\w*)+\s+(?:string|integer|boolean)\s*(?:primary)?(?:\s*,\s*(?:[a-z]\w*)\s+(?:string|integer|boolean)\s*(?:primary)?)*))

I am testing this expression to split up this statement:

> TABLE GENERATOR tableName (columnName string, column2 boolean primary)

The expression splits my test statement into 2 groups:

> - Group1: tableName
> - Group2: columnName string column2 boolean primary

I was wondering if there was a way to split group2 even further or split the group into a string array or list?

I have tried implementing `.split(), .toArray()`, and other similar methods onto group2 to try to split it as well as messing around on Regex however I have been at this for a while now and cannot seem to find a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do too much in one go. You wouldn't create a readable program by trying to put the entire thing on one line. For your columns spec, can simplify the regex to just look for occurrences of the entire group that does your column declaration:

```
[a-z]+ (bool|int)( primary)?
```

Will match 3 times:

```
x (cola bool, colb int, colc int primary)
   ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your regex engine will now have a matches collection of 3 matches (rather than one match with 3 capture groups) that is all your column bits. assuming your declaration of column name, type, modifiers, comma is consistent you should leverage this to pull your column info out. Rather than try to build one massive regex to do this, stick to a simple one that will just match repeatedly the column spec like I did here, and run another different regex to pull the table name out